# Introducing type abbreviations in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I know how to make "term abbreviations" in Isabelle, but can I make "type abbreviations" that behave in the same way?

I can define a "term abbreviation" using

```ml
abbreviation "foo == True"
```

Henceforth all appearances of `True` in the output will be printed as `foo`. For instance, the command

```ml
term "True ⟶ False"
```

outputs `"foo ⟶ False"`. I would like to define a "type abbreviation" that has this same behaviour. I know about the `type_synonym` command, but when I type

```ml
type_synonym baz = "int list"
```

then appearances of `int list` in future output are *not* replaced with `baz` as I would like them to be. If it doesn't already exist in some form, I think a `type_abbreviation` command could be quite handy when the right-hand side of the definition is rather unwieldy.

Comment: I don't think that there is a good solution. In general it is not clear when you really would like to replace types by their abbreviation. Of course the same holds for terms (but for terms ambiguities occur less frequently). E.g., when working on a theory on infinite sequences, I thought it was a good idea to use the abbreviation `'a seq` for `nat => 'a`. But would you really like to replace all occurrences of this type? I don't. Consider `nth :: 'a list => 'a seq`.

Comment: @chris Mm, good point, I guess `'a seq` should stay a `type_synonym` rather than a `type_abbreviation`. As a counterexample, though, I think I'd always prefer to see `string` instead of `char list`.

Comment: By the way, one possible workaround that I'm aware of is to introduce a constructor, e.g. `datatype baz = Baz "int list"`. One can then tag terms with `Baz` to make Isabelle print the type as `baz` type rather than `int list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare syntax translations for types just as it had to be done for terms before `abbreviation` was introduced. For example, the following makes Isabelle pretty-print `char list` as `string`. More examples of this kind can be found in the Isabelle distribution in [MicroJava](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/4dd08fe126ba/src/HOL/MicroJava/J/Decl.thy#l30).

```
translations
  (type) "string" <= (type) "char list"
```

The command `translations` works for type abbreviations where each type variable occurs exactly once on each side. If you have multiple occurrences of a type variable on the right hand side, you have to write a parse translation in ML. Examples of this can be found in [JinjaThreads](http://sourceforge.net/p/afp/afp-2013-2/ci/default/tree/thys/JinjaThreads/Framework/FWState.thy) in the AFP (search for `print_translation`).